# Como criar uma lista com Meses para alterar o resultado do DataTable?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Tenho um `dataTable` que traz os dados de um mês especifico setado na DAO.

Gostaria de criar um campo onde eu seleciono o mês e ele atualiza a tabela com o mês selecionado.

Tem que usar ajax?

Comment: Poste o que você já fez até agora para melhor compreensão.

Answer (score 0):

Para selecionar um mês de um ano, use o componente [Calendar](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/calendar.xhtml). Você vai ter que ignorar o dia, mas funciona.

Se você olhar a [documentação](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_0.pdf) vai ver que existe um atributo chamado `update` que pode ser usado para atualizar outro componente quando uma data for selecionada e o evento `dateSelect` ocorrer.

Exemplo baseado documentação:

```xml
<p:calendar value="#{calendarBean.date}">
    <p:ajax event=”dateSelect” listener=”#{bean.handleDateSelect}” update=”<id da tabela ser atualizada>” />
</p:calendar>
```

O método `handleDateSelect()` pode executar alguma lógica necessário, mas o importante é que o método que gera os valores do `dataTable` leia o valor de `calendarBean.date` e extraia o mês e o ano para atualizar a tabela.